# What are requirements to graduate from "Beta"?

Tags: support

I am new to the site and am excited to share with friends and help build the community. Where can I read/learn what requirements have to be met to graduate from Beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need enough visits, active & total users, answered questions (percentage of questions that have been answered), questions per day and a good answer ratio (how many answers per question). You can follow the StackExchange site process at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

See these pages for details:

- [What does "beta" mean?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta)
- [Homebrewing beta current status](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc)